# how to handle this problem of"inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found" when trying to add a grid layout

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

while dragging and dropping the grid layout into the design of my app,I get the following message:-
This operation requires the library com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:+.

Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:
-   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0
and:
-   com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0

With the dependency:
-   com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
versus:
-   com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0

The project may not compile after adding this library.
Would you like to add it anyway?

What should I do???Please help.

i have only 7 days of experience with android.
I am using android 3.4.1 for Windows 64-bit.

Below are the gradle dependencies:-

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

The app gradle is:-

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.connect3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and this is the other one that has the project name on it:-

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

                 }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
                  }
                 }

    allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

                 }
                }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
                             }
```

Comment: can you paste your gradle dependencies here?

Comment: i have edited the question and posted the dependencies

Comment: share your app/build.gradle

Comment: edited again. Please help.

Comment: I tried making new project with same gradle configurations, it is working fine. only this value is different 'minSdkVersion 25'.

Comment: i will try doing the same then. Thanks man for all the effort. Bless you.

Comment: it worked!!!!!! Bless you !!! bless you!!!